# How to make a custom semantics HLSL shader for the pixel shader

Tags: shaders, hlsl

I'm pretty sure it's possible but i have no idea how.

Could anyone tell me how to make a custom semantic for a pixel shader.

Thanks

Comment: do you need single value (same for all pixels) or do you need value per vertex?

Comment: Each vertex has a value set for it, just a texture index (basically it is which texture should be used on that vertex) and then each pixel needs its color set depending on the texture index. So yeah i just need an integer passed through the vertexshader and into the pixel shader...

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70821/do-the-predefined-hlsl-semantics-carry-any-meaning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, you just use `TEXCOORD` for any data that DX doesn't understand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509647(VS.85).aspx

This page suggests that the system doesn't give a crap, effectively, what semantics you give to your pixel shader inputs.

Comment: What if i just need an integer? I don't really need a multidimensional float.

Comment: @Randomman: I'm pretty sure that you can give any input value `TEXCOORD`. semantics.

Comment: Yep k i got it :D ill just use it as a Vertex2D using the x value, because i have a feeling i will change it to need two values later anyway.