# Do the predefined HLSL semantics carry any meaning?

Tags: hlsl, directx11, tessellation

I'd say there are 3 kinds of HLSL semantics:

- `SV_*` group - these are "system value" semantics which DO carry special meanings (e.g. assign special input/output data to/from shader stages)
- predefined semantics - e.g. `NORMAL`, `POSITION` and so on... They are mentioned in the docs but I failed to find any special meaning assigned to them
- semantics defined be the user - which can be anything (e.g. `MY_AWESOME_TEXTURE_SEMANTIC`) which apparently have no special meaning either

In addition, the docs say that more than one input/output value can have the same semantic assigned (e.g. '`NORMAL2` and `NORMAL2`). I guess that it doesn't include the `SV_*` group, though.

So besides the first group - do semantics carry any meaning at all? Do they even serve any purpose at all? :P

Comment: In D3D10-11 there are actually no predefined semantics anymore besides the `SV_*` ones.  Predefined names like `NORMAL`, `POSITION` etc. were used in D3D9, and of course you can still use those names if you like, but as far as the compiler is concerned, they're user-defined semantics.  So there are only 2 kinds of semantics really: system values and user-defined ones.

Comment: @NathanReed I feel like your comment is the *real*, to-the-point answer to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do they even serve any purpose at all?

Yes for the user and developer of the shader, semantics conveys information about the intended use of a parameter. So you will know that `POSITION` is intended to be used as vertex position, `NORMAL` as vertex normal etc. Think of this as in-code documentation (not strictly the same though).

> Do semantics carry any meaning at all?

They don't carry a meaning for the system, as they are not interpreted, but again for the user. You don't want to give vertex position a NORMAL semantic, it's really like deceiving the user/developer of the shader, it's confusing, it's like writing wrong documentation.

Comment: Ok, so why are they there in the first place (we can document the code with comments)? Except the `SV_*` group, of course. Historical remains?

Comment: @NPS It's like the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter idiom used in some languages it gives the code more clarity. you can't force comments though.

Comment: So do you say **THE ONLY** reason for their existence is code clarity? :P

Comment: @NPS Yes. GLSL for example doesn't do that same, so if you want to tell the attributes semantics you do this by actually naming the parameters. For example you say, `in vec2 textureCoord`. if you said `in vec3 t` that could be texture coords or tangents. adding the semantics clarifies this without reading the code.